# How do I store username and password in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, password-protection, keychain

I use the KeyChain to store user's username and password. But I want to store my application's username and password to access my web service. How can I store this securely?

Comment: If you're already storing the username and password in Keychain, you're storing it securely. Just read it out of keychain when you need to use it.

Comment: Well that is what I'm doing... My question is how do I use a secure static username and password, which is different to the keychain to access my webService method?

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to store some sort of key that only allows your app to access your web service? Something different than the user's login/password?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "some sort of key that only allows your app to access your web service." This is not a solvable problem. It is always going to be possible for clients other than yours (or modified versions of yours) to connect to your web service if used by an authorized user. You must account for this on the server side.

If your point is that you want to provide some thin layer of obfuscation to prevent trivial access to your service, then you would put the credential in your code. You definitely don't want to put it in Keychain, since that is per-device, and you want per-application. I would recommend a long, random string of bytes.

Comment: Well I want to access the service from my app in different views. So, basically don't want to replicate the credential, everywhere in web Service call! Is it possible to put it in NSData and retrieve later time.

Comment: Of course. Put it in a Singleton. There are tons of articles on doing this. Here's one that includes the most modern patterns based on GCD: http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/11/09/using-the-singleton-pattern-in-objective-c-part-2/

Comment: Of course. Put it in a Singleton. There are tons of articles on doing this. Here's one that includes the most modern patterns based on GCD: http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/11/09/using-the-singleton-pattern-in-objective-c-part-2/